# pygame sprite sheet cutter is returning subsurface error, but size seems to be accurate

Tags: python, python-2.7, pygame, sprite, sprite-sheet

So I have this image file I got from OpenGameArt.org [image]

It is 576 X 256 pixels, so I have this function to extract images from it:

```
def sprite_sheet_load(colorKey, spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY, fileName):
    '''Purpose: to extract a sprite from a sprite sheet at the chosen location'''
    '''credit to Stackover flow user hammyThePig for original code'''

    sheet = pygame.image.load(fileName).convert() #loads up the sprite sheet. convert makes sure the pixel format is coherent
    sheet.set_colorkey(colorKey) #sets the color key

    sprite = sheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY)) #grabs the sprite at this location

    return sprite
```

And within the Player class of my game, I have this code that calls up the above function in for loops

```
    playerImages = []   #lists for the player images
    playerDeathImages = [] # ""

    ###Image Gathering Section VVV ####

    spriteXLoc = 0 #starting x location for the sprite
    spriteYLoc = 0 #starting y location for the sprite
    spriteXSize = 64
    spriteYSize = 64

    #Grab the images for the main character's walking poses
for y in range(0,9): #handle the columns of sprite sheet
    for x in range(0,4): #handle the rows of sprite sheet
                playerImages.append(sprite_sheet_load(black, spriteXLoc, spriteYLoc, spriteXSize, spriteYSize, "mainCharacter.png"))
                spriteXLoc += spriteXSize
    spriteXLoc = 0 #reset the inital x value
    spriteYLoc += spriteYSize #increment the y value
```

SpriteLocX gets to 576, the max length of the image, and by that point, it should reset and do the next row, but instead, I get a subsurface error stating that it went over, or more specifically:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "game.py", line 97, in <module>
        player = Player() #create a player object
      File "game.py", line 63, in __init__
        playerImages.append(sprite_sheet_load(black, spriteXLoc, spriteYLoc, spriteXSize, spriteYSize, "mainCharacter.png"))
      File "game.py", line 33, in sprite_sheet_load
        sprite = sheet.subsurface(pygame.Rect(spriteLocX, spriteLocY, spriteSizeX, spriteSizeY)) #grabs the sprite at this location
    ValueError: subsurface rectangle outside surface area

            spriteXLoc = 0 #reset the inital x value
            spriteYLoc += spriteYSize #increment the y value
```

I've used this code before with no issue.  What is going wrong?  Also, is there a more accurate way to get the Spirte Size X and Y dimensions besides dividing the width and height by the number of columns and rows respectively?

Comment: `dividing` is the only way if you don't know sprite size.

Comment: Use `print` to see `spriteLocX`, `spriteLocY`

Answer (score 0):

You try to get 9 rows and 4 columns - replace `x` range with `y` range

```
for y in range(0,4): #handle the rows of sprite sheet
    for x in range(0,9): #handle the colums of sprite sheet
```